# Booting Ubuntu on external HDD

Tags: bootloader, boot-repair

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my external HDD including the bootloader. The problem is that when I disconnect HDD my computer, the computer says grub not found. I want it to boot normally into Windows after disconnecting the HDD. But when HDD is connected I want it to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Change the boot order back to the internal HDD in BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @CelticWarrior if I do that, it always boots into Windows.

Comment: Of course. Change it back to the external one or use the one-time boot key whenever you need.

Comment: The alternative is to move `/boot` (which includes Grub) onto a partition on the internal drive and reconfigure the Ubuntu installation accordingly. Changing the boot order may be annoying but the alternative is not trivial at all – especially if you're new to that kind of stuff – and may lead to other issues later-on since it's a less common, less tested system configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PC runs Windows 8 or Windows 10, it replaces BIOS with UEFI, which by default uses secure boot. This prevents you from booting into a non-Windows operating system.

To fix this, I would recommend doing what I did when I was in your situation. Enter your BIOS menu and go over to the tab with boot orders. There should be a setting with [UEFI] in it. Go over to this value, and change it to [LEGACY BIOS]. Save the settings, plug in your hard drive, and reboot. When you're ready to go back to Windows, turn off the computer, unplug the hard drive, and put the setting back at [UEFI].